# jQuery event handler closure

Tags: jquery, ajax, closures, jquery-events

When clicking a button for the first time, I'd like to have the event handler do a JSON request and return a function that handles any further clicks on the button. How can I achieve this without binding and unbinding event handlers on the button?

I'd like to just do the request and then let the returned event handler just
show or hide a DOM element, without going through the entire function again (cache check etc.)

**Pseudo code**

```
var setuphandler = (function(){
    // get json, setup dom etc.
    // ...

    // return the actual
    // show/hide function here
    return function(){
       $(img).toggle();
    }
});

$('button').on('click', handler());
```

[A sample JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UgfLb/)

Comment: Perhaps putting a .done(function(){}); at the end of the ajax?

Comment: Have you actually read the code?

Comment: Is a BaconJS solution ok @PHearst ?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm sure BaconJS handles the problem, but I was looking for a solution that only relies on jQuery

Comment: @PHeart - yes, I actually read the code, then noted the very classy url...and was ".done" there.

Comment: Impossible, since .click doesn't unwrap, is extending jquery ok?

Comment: @TimSPQR Your idea of 'classy url' is .fail

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yeah, I'm just interested in what solutions there are to this problem.

Comment: @PHearst this is a problem you shouldn't be having in the first place, there: http://jsfiddle.net/ce2nZ/ , I still don't get what you're trying to solve.

Comment: If you've solved your own question, then the proper procedure here on SO is (not to put the answer in the question), but to create your own answer with your solution and submit that.  You can even accept your own answer if you want.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks Benjamin, see my own solution for an explanation.

Comment: Look up the "deferred anti pattern"

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum You're more than welcome to correct me, I just can't see a better solution right now..

Comment: There is no sense in being precise if you...

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Sorry, if I was being unclear. The example here is a simplified mirror of something more complex. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need to create your own deferred object at all here.  It seems you can just assign `aboutpage` at the end of your `.done()` handler or just use a flag to keep track of whether this is the first time:

```
var aboutpage = function() {
      $.ajax({
            url:"your url here",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false
      }).done(function(data){
            var resp = data.posts[0]['photo-url-75'];
            var aboutEl = $('<img/>', {src: resp});
            $('#container').append(aboutEl);

            // assign aboutpage so the next click will just toggle
            aboutpage = function() {
                $('img').toggle();
            };            
      });
 };

$('#showcontent').on('click', function(){
     aboutpage();
};
```

You also could just use a flag:

```
function aboutpage() {
    if (!aboutpage.gotJSON) {
         // the first time this is called, retrieve JSON data
         aboutpage.gotJSON = true;
         $.ajax({
            url:"your url here",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false
         }).done(function(data){
            var resp = data.posts[0]['photo-url-75'];
            var aboutEl = $('<img/>', {src: resp});
            $('#container').append(aboutEl);
         });
    } else {
        // subsequent times, just toggle
        $('img').toggle();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first answer is true, deferred isn't needed here. The JSFiddle is a simplified example in a larger codebase, where the deferred way made sense. Anyhow, thanks for simplifying.

Answer (score 0):

Do you looking for something like [this(link to fiddle)?](http://jsfiddle.net/n7A3D/)

```
$(function(){
  var aboutpage = (function() {

    var $img;
    return function(data){
      if($img != undefined) {
        $img.toggle()
      } else {
        $.ajax({
          url:"http://fuckyeahbrutalism.tumblr.com/api/read/json",
          dataType: "jsonp", cache: false
        }).done(function(data) {
          var resp = data.posts[0]['photo-url-75'];
          $img = $('<img/>', {
              src: resp
          });
          $('#container').append($img);
        });
      }
    }
  })();
  $('#showcontent').on('click', aboutpage);
});
```

Comment: This can also make multiple requests

Comment: It stills returns the entire function, I'm looking to find a solution that returns just the toggling as the event handler.